# How do I get an array of strings in my string recourse file into the ListView of a ListFragment?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-listview, android-listfragment

It's my understanding that a ListFragment is just a Fragment that automatically has a ListView in it's layout. I have an array of Strings in my XML string resource file, and I've got a class that extends ListFragment called UrlListFragment.

Here's the array:

```
<string-array name="list_array">
    <item>http://www.microsoft.com</item>
    <item>http://www.xbox.com</item>
    <item>http://www.windowsphone.com</item>
</string-array>
```

And here's my extened ListFragment:

```
public class UrlListFragment extends ListFragment {

private static String[] urlList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view;
        Resources res = getActivity().getResources();
        urlList = res.getStringArray(R.array.list_array);
        view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        return view;

    }
}
```

How can I add the array of strings to the ListFragment so that every entry in the array is an entry in the list?

Answer (score 0):

A list fragment has a `setAdapter()` method.

You can create a simple adapter with:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, urlList);
```

And then, you just have to do:

```
setListAdapter(adapter);
```